# Advanced search in HTML table with Jquery

Tags: javascript, jquery

I am trying to search html table using jquery, and from examples seen in internet i managed to get it to work, but i would like to do more advanced search.

I want search to include also next row from matched row (regardless if there is any match there), how could i achieve this ?

I have this HTML at moment:

```js
$("#myInput").on("keyup", function () {
    var value = $(this).val().toLowerCase();
    $("tbody tr").filter(function () {
        $(this).toggle($(this).text().toLowerCase().indexOf(value) > -1)
    });
});
```

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">

<head>
    <meta charset="UTF-8">
    <title>Document</title>
</head>
<body>
    <p>
        <input id="myInput" type="text" placeholder="Search..">
        <script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.6.0/jquery.min.js"></script>
    </p>

    <table>
        <thead>
            <tr>
                <th style='text-align:left;'>Item</th>
            </tr>
        </thead>
        <tbody>
            <tr>
                <td>Porsche</td>
            </tr>
            <tr>
                <td>Joe</td>
            </tr>
            <tr>
                <td>Ferrari</td>
            </tr>
            <tr>
                <td>John</td>
            </tr>
            <tr>
                <td>Lada</td>
            </tr>
            <tr>
                <td>Vladimir</td>
            </tr>
        </tbody>
    </table>
</body>
</html>
```

So goal would be to always include +1 row to matched row ,for example if i would search Ferrari, i would like it to show Ferrari row and John row.

Comment: Is it possible to amend the HTML? It would make more sense to group the contain both 'Ferrari' and 'John' (in your example) in to the same `tr`.

Comment: That's not how `.filter()` is supposed to be used... -> [`$.filter()`](https://api.jquery.com/filter/). If used correctly you would get a collection of "matching" rows. Then just iterate over these rows and "show" them + the `.next()` one.

Comment: As above: you're using `.filter` as a `.each`.   https://jsfiddle.net/yjzbcuon/

Answer (score 1):

```js
 $("#myInput").on("keyup", function () {
    var value = $(this).val().toLowerCase();
    $("tbody tr").filter(function () {
        if ($(this).text().toLowerCase().indexOf(value) > -1) {
            $(this).addClass("filteredNode");
        }
        else {
            $(this).removeClass("filteredNode");
        }
        $(this).toggle($(this).text().toLowerCase().indexOf(value) > -1)
    });
});
```

```css
.filteredNode + tr {
    display: table-row !important;
}
```

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">
<head>
    <meta charset="UTF-8">
    <title>Document</title>

    <style>
      
    </style>
</head>
<body>
    <p>
        <input id="myInput" type="text" placeholder="Search..">
        <script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.6.0/jquery.min.js"></script>
    </p>

    <table>
        <thead>
            <tr>
                <th style='text-align:left;'>Item</th>
            </tr>
        </thead>
        <tbody>
            <tr>
                <td>Porsche</td>
            </tr>
            <tr>
                <td>Joe</td>
            </tr>
            <tr>
                <td>Ferrari</td>
            </tr>
            <tr>
                <td>John</td>
            </tr>
            <tr>
                <td>Lada</td>
            </tr>
            <tr>
                <td>Vladimir</td>
            </tr>
        </tbody>
    </table>
</body>
</html>
```